# recalculateFormulas() causing UnexpectedException: Unable to create/update fields: IsDeleted

Tags: formula-field, sobject, winter16, unexpectedexception

When I update my custom Record__c a trigger runs, and it calls `recalculateFormulas()` on the record. This results in the following error:

> System.UnexpectedException: Unable to create/update fields: IsDeleted.
>   Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is
>   read/write for your profile or permission set.

Same thing happens when I update Record__c inside a unit test. The object has several cross-object and non-cross-object formula fields.

Any ideas what's causing this error?

Comment: Sounds like a possible bug....If it is I can't believe it made it out as that type should have been caught...(never would have worked)

Comment: @Eric I'm seeing similar issues after using recalculateFormulas() for the first time today : `Opportunity: bad field names on insert/update call: Account, Owner` - the irony is that if I hadn't read this OP a few days ago, I wouldn't have known this new method has been added :-(

Comment: For reference, see also: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/100627/2602

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score -3):

Are you trying to update IsDelete field from cose in trigger? If so can you just use delete dml on such objects where you want to set IsDelete as true.

Comment: That's an immutable system field..