# Cascade delete records

Tags: apex, trigger, lookup, hierarchy, cascadedelete

I have one object, for example `Area`. It has two lookup relationships to itself, `Parent__c`, `Child__c`. In result I can create record with `Parent` and `Child` parameters. I am trying build hierarchy.

And when I delete a record, I want delete all of its children, and children of its children, ad infinitum. Long story short, imitation of `Master Detail` relationship. Why don't I use `Master Detail`? Because a `Master Detail` relationship cannot refer an object to itself.

How can I resolve?

Answer (score 4):

I've only done this for immediate children (admittedly for separate parent/child SObjects - see Dmitriy's comment), but assume this trigger approach will work:

```
trigger AreaTrigger on Area__c (before delete) {
    Set<Id> ids = Trigger.oldMap.keySet();
    delete [
            select Id from Area__c
            where Parent__c in :ids
            or Parent__r.Parent__c in :ids
            or Parent__r.Parent__r.Parent__c in :ids
            or Parent__r.Parent__r.Parent__r.Parent__c in :ids
            or Parent__r.Parent__r.Parent__r.Parent__r.Parent__c in :ids
            ]);
}
```

Only up to 5 levels of parent relationship can be traversed in the above manner, so if you need to support arbitrary depth, a looped solution where multiple queries are done will be needed.

See e.g. [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com) for more explanation about relationships (`__r` values).

Comment: You could also create an `Ultimate Parent` [formula](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113265/need-help-on-soql-to-query-all-related-child-case-records/113276).

Comment: Its bad solution because, triggerrs not allow recursively delete itself records.

Comment: @Dmitriy OK. If you have a solution yourself now add it - you can accept your own answer - or if not someone else will hopefully answer.

Comment: Wow that's rude...and doesn't even seem like a valid objection.

Comment: @Dmitriy You can write the delete code in a separate class which will be called multiple times as the trigger delete each child records

Comment: @KeithC If we know there'll be less than 16 levels of recursion, just delete the immediate children, as those children will then recursively delete their children...