# How is a salesforce custom field with htmlFormatted attribute created?

Tags: html, custom, test-setup

So I know about text areas and rich text areas (extraTypeInfo). But a customer has some custom fields which are string types but with htmlFormatted = true returned in metadata. Looks like this is just an HTML fragment, fairly similar to the rich text areas.

But I am not sure how to create such a custom field for testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the [Apex field describe documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe)

> isHtmlFormatted()
>
> Returns true if the field has been formatted for HTML and should be
>   encoded for display in HTML, false otherwise. One example of a field
>   that returns true for this method is a hyperlink custom formula field.
>   Another example is a custom formula field that has an IMAGE text
>   function.

Since these are formula fields, you can't mock their values, only fetch via SOQL after an object is saved or use `mySobj.recalculateFormulas()` (although, [see limitations](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100627/winter-16-recalculateformulas-fails-when-sobject-has-relationship-fields))

Comment: Yep I figured this out using the HYPERLINK method. Thanks for responding