# Setting/mocking out formula fields during tests

Tags: apex, unit-test, formula-field

We have an object (let's call it Child) with a formula field that does a lot of checking of various fields and spits out a numeric result (estimated number of days some work will take, based on a bunch of flags and conditions).

Another object (Parent) has multiple Children related to it through a lookup.

I wrote an apex class that aggregates the Children of a Parent in various ways based on several fields, including the formula result. I now want to test that logic, but when I try to create some sample Children to feed into my test, I'm told that I can't write to formula fields.

I don't want to figure out how to build a tree of objects and set specific fields to get the value I want to test from the formula field. Furthermore, the formula has a limited set of results, which may change in the future (say, the business decides that some particular type of work takes 8 days instead of 10). I want to test various edge cases that the formula can't produce today.

What's the best approach to this?

Answer (score 13):

Since recalculateFormulas() still has a bug, you can use this as a work around to set formula fields:

```
@TestVisible
private static SObject setFormulafield(SObject sObj, String fieldName, Object value)
{
    String jsonString = JSON.serialize(sObj);
    Map<String,Object> dataMap = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
    dataMap.put(fieldName, value);
    jsonString = JSON.serialize(dataMap);
    return (SObject)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, SObject.class);
}
```

Also a nice thing to use when Mocking.

Answer (score 3):

The general solution to this problem is two-fold

1. If the formula logic is especially complex and you want to maintain a regression test suite for it, build an apex testmethod just for it, passing in various combinations of inputs.  How you create that test input can be explicitly via APEX SObject construction or perhaps with a library of JSON data kept in a StaticResource
2. Use a `@TestVisible` property in your code that returns the value of the formula field such as this:

   ```
   @TestVisible
   public Decimal theFormulaFieldVal {
    {get
      return theFormulaFieldVal == null 
        ? theSobject.realFormulaField 
        : theFormulaFieldVal;
    }
    set;
   }
   ```

Your code never refers to the `sobject.formulaField`, instead replace all such references to this special property

Then, in your testmethod, after constructing the class,

```
 theClass.theFormulaField = 10; // mocked value
 // now invoke the class's methods
```

This way, the formula field returns a constant 10 regardless of use case in testmethods and returns the actual formula value in PROD use cases.

Should the above be too limiting, you can write a more sophisticated mockable facade using your own class with injection via constructor arguments - similar to how HttpMock works.

Answer (score 2):

As for *setting* the value, you really only control the inputs and do, as you say, have to *set specific fields to get the value I want*. If you want the field to be writeable, move the formula to a `Workflow Field Update`, and add something in your `Workflow Rule` criteria to prevent overwrites.

If you want to be able to *get* the value without the overhead of an insert/query, try the `SObject` method `recalculateFormulas()` method. From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm):

> **recalculateFormulas()**
> Recalculates all formula fields on an sObject, and sets updated field values. Rather than inserting or updating objects each time you want to test changes to your formula logic, call this method and inspect your new field values. Then make further logic changes as needed.
>
> **Signature**
> public Void recalculateFormulas()
>
> **Return Value**
> Type: Void
>
> **Usage**
> This method doesn’t recalculate cross-object formulas. If you call this method on objects that have both cross-object and non-cross-object formula fields, only the non-cross-object formula fields are recalculated.
>
> **See Also:**
> [What Are Cross-Object Formulas?](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_cross_object.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean I should blow away the formula logic during the test, replace it with a static number, call `recalculateFormulas()`, and then undo the changes? Is this possible?

Comment: The formula will still calculate the same as if it were in the database. You have to set up the input data so it yields the values you want. I don't think there's any way around that. This just helps you if you don't want to insert and re-query the data.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is specifically that setting up the input data is lots of work at best, and impossible at worst. The formula has a limited set of outputs, so there's no input combination that will produce some of the outputs I want to test.

Comment: @Egor Your only other option that I know of is to move the logic to PB/WFR. Or move it to a trigger and then you have *lots* of control...but the calculation may be harder to configure.

Comment: @Egor - One of the reasons to consider when you find something difficult to test or not future proof is that your implementation may not be ideal.

Comment: `recalculateFormulas()` has one [limitation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100627/winter-16-recalculateformulas-fails-when-sobject-has-relationship-fields) that hopefully will get fixed

Comment: @crop It's in the documentation I quoted, so I wouldn't hold my breath: *This method doesn’t recalculate cross-object formulas. If you call this method on objects that have both cross-object and non-cross-object formula fields, only the non-cross-object formula fields are recalculated.*

Comment: the limitation is on presence of `lookup fields` in the sobject in memory, not cross-obj formulas.