# System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable:

Tags: code-coverage, error-messages, failing-tests

We have the following code and Apex Test Class, and for some reason during Apex Test Execution (Developer Console-->Run Test) it is throwing the following error message below. Any ideas why the field could not be writable? The field in question is a   Long Text Area(32768). I checked that the user has CRUD on the object as well as FLS read/write on the field. I even gave the profile "Modify All" on the object and still the error below.

System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: My_API_Logs__c.My_Request__c

EDIT: It seems like the only way to go around is to set the apex to "Without Sharing". This is strange and seems like a bug.

```
    public with sharing class My_API_Log {
 public static My_API_Log__c setErrorLogs(String strRequest, String strResponse, String strCode, String strErrorDetails, Id strContactId, String strType){
        try{
            My_API_Logs__c objError = new My_API_Logs__c();
            objError.My_Request__c = strRequest;
            objError.My_Response__c = strResponse;
            objError.My_Status_Code__c = strCode;
            objError.My_Error_Details__c = strErrorDetails;
            objError.My_Contact__c = strContactId;
            objError.My_Type__c = strType;
            return objError;
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw e;
        }
    }   
}
```

And the line of code that is failing is where the "insert" statement line is below: (DISCLAIMER: this is just a code snippet for simplicity)

```
public with sharing class MyClass {
    public static list<My_API_Log__c> lstLogs = new lits<My_API_Log__c>();
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string myMethod(){
       string strresult = 'test';

       HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
       if(req.getStatusCode() == 200){
       
           insert My_API_Log.setErrorLogs('Test', 'Test,'Test', 'Test',null, 'Test'); //This is where its erroring out!
       }
    
       return strresult;
    }
}
```

Apex Test Class

```
@isTest(seeAllData=false)
public class MyClassTest{
    static testMethod void testMyMethod(){
        //Created Account
        //Created Contact
        //Created the Contact as a User (CustomerCommunityUser).
 
        System.runAs(CustomerCommunityUser){
        Test.startTest();

        Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();
        headers.put('Content-Type','application/json');


        
        MyClassMock mock= new MyClassMock(
            200,
            'success',
            'success',
            headers
        );
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mockFailure);

        String str = MyClass.myMethod();
        Test.stopTest();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the data type for My_Request__c?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting/mocking out formula fields during tests](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139286/setting-mocking-out-formula-fields-during-tests)

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, the My_Request__c field is a Long Text Area(32768).

Comment: @RenatoOliveira - the field is a Long Text Area(32768) and not a formula field. Unfortunately, the article does not apply in my situation.

Comment: Are you sure the error is on that field/line? This error usually happesn with lookup fields...

Comment: Also, could you provide us with the test class' code?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira I added the test class and am sure the error is on that field when I debugged the code that is the exact error message --> System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: My_API_Logs__c.My_Request__c

Comment: The one piece of note I would add is that it only fails and errors out when I'm running the test as the community user System.runAs(CustomerCommunityUser)

Comment: @RenatoOliveira another thing I noticed is that if I specify "without sharing" the test class is passing and its not erroring out with that LongTextArea field.

Comment: It seems like the only way to go around is to set the apex to "Without Sharing". This is strange and seems like a bug.